# What's the fastest way to render a scrolling text?

Tags: rendering, performance

I'm trying to render scrolling text (well, in 2.79, because I'm outdated)
I tried rendering ordinary 3D text and it took about 2+ seconds per frame.
So I tried rendering the text to an image 1920 x 8000 and translated it in the compositor. Somehow that resulted in 0.4 seconds per frame (fine with me). Only problem is that I can't recreate that speed anymore and now the compositor takes 2+ seconds per  frame as well.

So, which way results in the fastest rendering speed? It's just a static image that gets moved around.

Comment: Depending on what the text should look like, an emission shader is very fast at 1 sample if only text is visible...

Comment: the look is as plain as can be. one color text, 2D with a font of my choice, properly anti-aliased. Nothing fancy. If a pre-rendered graphic is faster, then the more generic question would be: what's the fastest way to shove an image around?

I'll try the emission shader...preferrably right now ( :

Comment: Since I am using the university library, no electricity at home, I used a fresh copy of Blender and whoops, it's back to .4 seconds with the node editor. I wonder what I did wrong yesterday.

Comment: Funny enough, I was at .3, .4 seconds and when I set up rendering, it jumps to 1 second. Didn't change any settings. Might be the png creation, not sure. If I had the energy, I'd play detective.